# Gulp uglify output min.js

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

The js file being compressed is output with the same filename.

```
gulp.task('compressjs', function () {
  gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

How can I have it output the file with `min.js` at the back?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use the `suffix` or `extname` parameters of [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename) like:

```
gulp.task('compressjs', function () {
  gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

Comment: How would you update the html script tags to reflect the name change? I would like a gulp build that minified javascript files for production but not for development builds.

Comment: @NathanReese You could use a plugin like *gulp-rev-all* to do that

Comment: another (cleaner) way to do it is `.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))`

Comment: @intellion You're right, mind if I change it in the answer?

Comment: @Aperçu absolutely not :)

Comment: It's terrible that `gulp-clean-css` and `gulp-uglify` don't do this automagically. But this solution worked like charm. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to npm install gulp-rename and require it.